# How to make tomcat working behind reverse proxy?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Tomcat server, it runs well on $myip:8080. When I submitted a form on $myip:8080/test (), it will jump to $myip:8080/test/get_result and give out the correct result.

In order to see the result of $myip:8080/test when I access $myip/services/test,I rewrite the url in nginx's configuration and make it point to $myip:8080. The configuration is showing in the following:

```
location /services/ {
 rewrite /services/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

It is okay to access $myip/services/test, however when I submit the form it jumps to $myip/services/get_result. What should I do to make it jump to $myip/services/test/get_result instead？

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe your problem?